# Is it possible to capture the stdout from the sh DSL command in the pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

For example:

```
var output=sh "echo foo";
echo "output=$output";
```

I will get:

```
output=0
```

So, apparently I get the exit code rather than the stdout. Is it possible to capture the stdout into a pipeline variable, such that I could get:
`output=foo`
as my result?

Answer (score 268, accepted):

[Now](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26133), the [`sh` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) supports returning *stdout* by supplying the parameter `returnStdout`.

```java
// These should all be performed at the point where you've
// checked out your sources on the slave. A 'git' executable
// must be available.
// Most typical, if you're not cloning into a sub directory
gitCommit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()
// short SHA, possibly better for chat notifications, etc.
shortCommit = gitCommit.take(6)
```

See [this example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/gitcommit/gitcommit.groovy).

Comment: note the `.trim()` part of this answer, otherwise you may get a newline character at the end of the line

Comment: append `--short` to `rev-parse` can just directly obtain a short hash

Comment: not sure what causing failure but I had to convert output to string also like this `gitCommit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').toString().trim()`

Comment: hi, what '.take(6)' stands for?

Comment: @Vano that refers to the Groovy method take(), which will get the first 6 characters in this case. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.2/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#take(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)

Comment: In my case I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method trim() on null object` and it's only when I'm using `myvar.take()` in some other function, while it works with simple `sh 'echo'+myvar.take()`

Answer (score 49):

Note: The linked Jenkins issue has since been solved.

As mention in [JENKINS-26133](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26133) it was not possible to get shell output as a variable. As a workaround suggested using of writ-read from temporary file. So, your example would have looked like:

```groovy
sh "echo foo > result";
def output=readFile('result').trim()
echo "output=$output";
```

Comment: For newcomers, please see the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38912813/345845 below, this was since made easier with the new `returnStdout` parameter passed to the `sh` step.

Comment: "it's not possible to get shell output as a variable" - not true. This is a hack, the correct answer is returnStdout.

Comment: The only time this is actually a good answer is if you need **both** the `stdout` and the `exit status` from the shell command. Other times, use the `returnStdout` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
def get_git_sha(git_dir='') {
    dir(git_dir) {
        return sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()
    }
}

node(BUILD_NODE) {
    ...
    repo_SHA = get_git_sha('src/FooBar.git')
    echo repo_SHA
    ...
}
```

Tested on:

- Jenkins ver. 2.19.1
- Pipeline 2.4

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use as well this functions to capture StdErr StdOut and return code.

```
def runShell(String command){
    def responseCode = sh returnStatus: true, script: "${command} &> tmp.txt" 
    def output =  readFile(file: "tmp.txt")

    if (responseCode != 0){
      println "[ERROR] ${output}"
      throw new Exception("${output}")
    }else{
      return "${output}"
    }
}
```

Notice:

```
&>name means 1>name 2>name -- redirect stdout and stderr to the file name
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and tried almost everything then found after I came to know I was trying it in the wrong block. I was trying it in steps block whereas it needs to be in the environment block.

```
        stage('Release') {
                    environment {
                            my_var = sh(script: "/bin/bash ${assign_version} || ls ", , returnStdout: true).trim()
                                }
                    steps {                                 
                            println my_var
                            }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

A short version would be:

```
echo sh(script: 'ls -al', returnStdout: true).result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def listing = sh script: 'ls -la /', returnStdout:true
```

Reference : http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920064602.do Page 433