# How to pass shell variable to ansible playbook command

Tags: shell, jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I have this Jenkins pipeline where I need to run ansiblePlaybook() command with inventory file. Inventory file does contain date (current date) part (my-instance-ips-(mm-dd-yyyy)). Here, I am facing issue in creating currentDate variable and pass into pipeline script

**Jenkins File:**

```
pipeline {
    agent any   
     stages {
         stage ( 'Executing shell script' ) {
             steps {
                 script {
                     sh """
                     currentDate = "\$(date +'%m-%d-%Y')"
                     inventory_file = "my-instance-ips-{$currentDate}.yml"
                     
                     ansiblePlaybook (
                     playbook: 'task.yml',
                     inventory: $inventory_file,
                     installation: 'ansible-2.6.5','
                     -e "DATE = $currentDate")
                     """
                     }
                 }
             }
           }
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: currentDate for class: groovy.lang.Bindin
```

Could someone help me out to create current date in pipeline script and the same should pass over to ansible playbook command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are invoking ansible plugin. If that is what you are trying to achive, then your ansible playbook call should not be inside `sh` step.
You need to get the command's output first then invoke ansible plugin.

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
pipeline {
    agent any   
    stages {
         stage ( 'Executing shell script' ) {
             steps {
                 script {
/*                     currentDate = sh (
                         script: "date +'%m-%d-%Y'"
                         returnStatus: true
                     ).trim()
*/
                     cDate = java.time.LocalDate.now()
                     currentDate = cDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy"))
                     inventory_file = "my-instance-ips-${currentDate}.yml"
                     println inventory_file

                     ansiblePlaybook ([
                         playbook: 'task.yml',
                   //      credentialsId: 'xxxx',
                         disableHostKeyChecking: true,
                         inventory: "${inventory_file}",
                         extraVars: [
                             DATE: "${currentDate}"
                         ]
                     ])
                   }
                 }
             }
           }
}
```

Comment: I am getting ```unexpected token: returnStdout``` error for this code

Comment: Which Jenkins version you are using? It seems you need to update plugins and dependencies as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727104/jenkins-pipeline-sh-returnstdout-not-working

Comment: I've added another workaround to get the date. I've also corrected the extraVars section where I was using '=' instead of ':'

Comment: I tried with this, but getting ```java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep.setExtraVars() expects interface java.util.Map but received class java.util.ArrayList``` this error..

Comment: I don't think we need the extra vars anymore.. if we delete it, the code will be good!! thank you so much

Comment: ```expects interface java.util.Map but received class java.util.ArrayList``` error was due to the '=' inside extraVars map. Please see the updated code.