# Is it possible to send all output of the sh DSL command in the Jenkins pipeline to a file?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to de-clutter my Jenkins output. Thanks to [Is it possible to capture the stdout from the sh DSL command in the pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507410/is-it-possible-to-capture-the-stdout-from-the-sh-dsl-command-in-the-pipeline), I know I can send the output of each sh command to a file. However, the commands themselves will still be written to the Jenkins output instead of the file. For example:

```
sh '''echo "Hello World!"
    ./helloworld
    ./seeyoulater
'''
```

As is, this results in the Jenkins output looking like this:

```
echo "Hello World!"
Hello World!
./helloworld
<helloworld output, possibly many lines>
./seeyoulater
<seeyoulater output, possibly many lines>
```

However, if I send the output to a file, I get Jenkins output like this:

```
echo "Hello World!" > output.log
./helloworld >> output.log
./seeyoulater >> output.log
```

and output.log looking like this:

```
Hello World!
<helloworld output>
<seeyoulater output>
```

This leads to my Jenkins output being less cluttered, but output.log ends up not having any separators between the script outputs. I suppose I could have `echo <command>` right before each command, but that just means my Jenkins output gets more cluttered again.

Is there any way to send the entire output of the `sh` DSL command to a file? Basically something like `sh '''<commands here>''' > output.log` is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a solution, but I did find a workaround. As mentioned in the [sh command documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script), the default is to run using the `-xe` flags. The `-x` flag is why the commands are shown in the Jenkins output. The remedy is to add `set +x`:

```
sh '''set +x
    echo "Hello World!" > output.log
    ./helloworld >> output.log
    ./seeyoulater >> output.log
'''
```

The `set +x` shows up in the Jenkins output, but the rest of the commands do not. From there, it's just a matter of adding enough `echo` statements in there to make `output.log` sufficiently readable.