# How to set Jenkins DSL pipeline commands to variable in groovy?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to set the output of certain DSL plugin commands to env. variables in Jenkins DSL and having no luck.

I tried imitating the following way of setting sh scripts output to variables:

```
env.BUILD_NUM = sh([script: "get_build_number_from_s3 ${env.TARGET_ENV}", returnStdout: true]).trim()
```

The first one I'm trying to do is the git module.

I set my command like the following:

```
env.DEVOPS_REPO_CLONE = git([branch: "development", credentialsId: 'bitbucket', url: 'https://bitbucket.org/team/repo.git'])
sh 'ls -lah'
```

but I get the following error:

```
WorkflowScript: 119: Expected a step @ line 119, column 13.
               env.DEVOPS_REPO_CLONE = git([branch: "development", credentialsId: 'bitbucket', url: 'https://bitbucket.org/team/repo.git'])
               ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:559)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:520)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:319)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Basically, I'm trying to set the output of commands to variables, that way I can only show the output when DEBUG flag is set to abstract extraneous output for developers so they don't have to parse through pages of text.

Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be that you need to create these variables in `environment {...}` or `script { ... }` scope. Example:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        FOO = sh (
                script: 'pwd',
                returnStdout: true
              ).trim()
    }

    agent { label "master" }
    stages {
        stage("first") {
            steps {
                script {
                    BAR = sh (
                            script: 'ls',
                            returnStdout: true
                          ).trim()
                }
                sh "echo ${FOO}"
                sh "echo ${BAR}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use `returnStdout` or `returnStatus` options for shell scripts as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38912813/10721592) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38783622/10721592).

Comment: I'm not asking about how to run shell scripts I'm asking about how to run jenkins plugin commands from the declarative syntax and mute the output. I can mute the output of my shell scripts but when I run anchore plugin there is no option to mute output, or if I run git plugin I can't mute the output unelss I convert to shell commands and run them with sh script which I don't want to do. I want to mute the plugin output